# Cannot implicitly convert type ResponseBase to Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6.1

```
Response response = new Response();
```

This is the line that shows the error **'Cannot implicitly convert type ResponseBase to Response'**:

```
response = await BaseFlow.Invoke(jsonRawRequest, response);
```

...and it is calling:

```
public static async Task<ResponseBase> Invoke(JToken jsonRawRequest, ResponseBase responseBase)
        {...}
```

...and this is the **Response** class:

```
class Response : ResponseBase
    {
    // empty
    }
```

...and the **ResponseBase**:

```
public class ResponseBase
    {...}
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it say 'Cannot implicitly convert type Response to ResponseBase' instead of the other way arround, because I am trying to pass a class of Response to a method accepting ResponseBase? And how to fix it?

*I've browsed the internet and it claims that I sould be able to pass a derived class to a method accepting a base class.*

Comment: You assign the return value of await Invoke function, which is ResponseBase, to a variable of type Response. So you try to assign parent class instance to a variable of derived type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't when you're trying to pass `response` as parameter.

Error comes when your are trying to assign the result of `Invoke` (`ResponseBase` type) to `response` variable (`Response` type).

To fix it simply change `response` type to `ResponseBase`:

```
ResponseBase response = new Response();
```

or use a new `ResponseBase` variable.

Comment: Ahhhhh. Thank you. I am blind. Of course. Can accept your answer in 5 minutes, so - until then... Thank you!